# How to intercept third party library gcm

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

My app implements GCM. I am using a third party library that also implements GCM. When the message comes for the library, is there a way to intercept it (without damaging my app)?

One idea I am considering is to create a BroadcastReceiver that somehow knows when the GCM comes for the library and receives it that way (I don't care if the library gets notified as well; I just want to get it too).

BTW right now the library is not receiving its GCM at all because I too have a GCM. But, again, in any case I want my app to be able to get the library's GCM regardless whether the library gets it too

Comment: You would have to look into the inner workings of the library, also having multiple listeners for incoming GCM messages is not good. There should only be one listener and then it can broadcast to the rest of the app as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[About GCM Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server#top_of_page), in implementing GCM server you'll need to decide which GCM connection server protocol(s) you want to use to enable your app server to interact with GCM connection servers. Note that if you want to use upstream messaging from your client applications, you must use XMPP.

It was mentioned that one of two components in server side of Google Cloud Messaging is that:

> An application server that you must implement in your environment. This **application server sends data to a client app via the chosen GCM connection server**, using the appropriate XMPP or HTTP protocol.

Additionaly, regarding intercepting the GCM message with the use of `BroadcastReceiver`, it was noted in [Implementing GCM Client](http://wear.techbrood.com/google/gcm/server.html) that:

> If you have a relatively simple app that doesn't require a service, you can intercept the GCM message in a regular BroadcastReceiver and do your processing there. Once you get the intent that GCM passes into your broadcast receiver's `onReceive()` method, what you do with it is up to you.

More information and samples are given in documentations. Hope those help. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry if the question is a bit confusion. My GCM is working fine both before and after I included the 3rd party library. The question is only and specifically about intercepting GCM that were intended for the 3rd party library that is part of my app.